# suggest for svn configuration for TAG

Tags: svn

I have a doubt. I would like to do a configuration in SVN, but I don't know if it is possible.
I have my project which a new tag is released weekly, and it have to be deployed.

I remember that sometime ago I seen an SVN repository that in the tags folder have a tag named LAST_UPDATED.

I thought, if is it possible to create like a symbolic link that is updated for each tag I create.

Example:
My last tag is */application-1.0.1*
when I create a tag */application-1.0.2*
The tag *LAST_UPDATED* will point to this new version.

Is it possible? Can it cause some problems?
Or is there another way to have a folder in SVN which is always the latest release we do?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let me first remid you that `tags`, `branches` and `trunk` are all just concepts and that in SVN, they're all simple copies.

Having that said, an SVN tag is a snapshot copy of a branch and SVN won't prevent you from modifying the content of a tag. You can use pre-commit hooks to handle this if you need it. The idea behind the classic use of tag is that when you release the version 1 of your software, you can copy your code base to a tag and you do the same when releasing version 2, version 3 and so on. Then when you need it, you can retreive how your code was like for version X.

So to come back to your need, you should either:

- create tags for each release as you already do, and keep track of which one is the current release in another system. If your tag naming habit is simple enough, a script can easily browse all of them to retreive the last one.
- or use a `stable` branch on which you always have the current release code. Then you commit daily to another branch (that can be the `trunk` or a special branch for every new feature for instance) and merge the change you have validated to the `stable` branch. When a version is released, a tag can be created from this branch.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is this, e.g.:

```
svn cp trunk tags/application-1.0.2
svn delete tags/LAST_UPDATED
svn cp tags/application-1.0.2 tags/LAST_UPDATED
svn ci -m"New production tag"
```

First time around you do not need to delete `tags/LAST_UPDATED`, of course.